# Easiest way to back up the Visual Studio Code files for my Marlin 3D printer

Tags: backup

I want to know what would be the easiest and fastest way to back up the Visual Studio Code files for my CoreXY 3D Printer. I worry about losing my setup files if my SSD would get corrupted, etc.

Would appreciate any answers I can get.

Lorne Wilkins

Should I just copy the whole folder?